# Regex error? - Is not deleting?

Tags: php, regex

Finally I found my last error in my code but this time it is very confusing... As you can see in the code, the Output should be   (Nothing). But I still get `Mitgliedschaft Card (Weltweit)`.

Why isn't it deleting this phrase? - It should only get deleted if the case `\b` is active.

```
$deletewords = ["Mitgliedschaft Card (Weltweit)", "(Xbox 360/Xbox One/weltweit)", "Origins", "Guthaben Code - nur DE", "Guthaben Code für EA ORIGIN", "PC - nur DE"];

$myArra = ["Mitgliedschaft Card (Weltweit)", "Guthaben Code - nur DE", "Guthaben Code für EA ORIGIN", "PC - nur DE"];

foreach ($myArra as $string){
    $string = mb_eregi_replace('\b' . implode('|', $deletewords) . '\b', '', $string);
    echo $string;
}
```

It is confusing that all other words get deleted but `Mitgliedschaft Card (Weltweit)` is still there...

Comment: Can you clarify the question. I suspect that "My isn't he deleting this word?" means "Why isn't it deleting this phrase?".

Comment: You are right, sorry... And I still get this error..

Comment: Because there're no wordboundaries between `)` and end of string.

Comment: What do you mean? - It is one string who is equal to the other? - Could you maybe post the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're no word boundaries between `)` and end of string in `Mitgliedschaft Card (Weltweit)`. A word boundary exists only between a word character and a NON word character.

Moreover, parenthesis are special character in a regex, you have to escape them, here is a way to go using `preg_quote`:

```
$deletewords = ["Mitgliedschaft Card (Weltweit)", "(Xbox 360/Xbox One/weltweit)", "Origins", "Guthaben Code - nur DE", "Guthaben Code für EA ORIGIN", "PC - nur DE"];

$myArra = ["Mitgliedschaft Card (Weltweit)", "Guthaben Code - nur DE", "Guthaben Code für EA ORIGIN", "PC - nur DE"];

function quote($x) { return preg_quote($x);}
$deletewords = array_map('quote', $deletewords);
$allwords =  implode('|', $deletewords)
foreach ($myArra as $string) {
    $string = mb_eregi_replace('(?:' . $allwords . ')', '', $string);
    echo $string,"\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is preg_quote multibyte safe and if not is there a way to make it multibyte safe?

Comment: And I should turn into a `\b(?:' . $allwords . ')\b` quote, or? - Because I just want to delete the words if they are like in my deletewords array and not if there is a word e.g. `This is a Mitgliedschaft Card for everything`

Comment: @Jan: Not sure. But I think it does.

Comment: This is the answer to comment 1 or 2 from me? :)

Comment: @Jan: from comment 1.

Comment: @Jan: I just could say: "try it on all your test cases"